# Question about Timeline, does the user have to be connected?

Tags: iframe, authentication, facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-timeline

The reason I'm asking is because, right now we already have it setup to prompt users to share things if they're connected. But the biggest problem we have is that without the user being connected, it tries to make a popup window — which is blocked in most browsers. (vs. the iframe inline)

So, I'm trying to see what the benefit or difference in us implementing the new changes if we're already doing "timeline-like" sharing. I don't get it? Do we have to recode everything?

Last, off topic, but I'm confused about the way the referral API works actually, because the same code doesn't seem to invoke the API at all. Just display the user's name

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the users "publish_actions" permission to add things to timeline. So in that sense, yes, they do need to be connected. But the advantage of that is that once you get "publish_actions" permission, the user never needs to be prompted... you just automatically share the actions they've taken by making api calls.

Comment: So, if we're prompting users to "Share" voluntarily right now ... there's really no benefit in implementing this unless we wanted to auto-share?

Comment: right, and if you want to auto-share, it has to be actions using open graph api. It's a very different concept from "sharing" in the traditional sense.